# How do I use the rug function for an exponential distribution in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, exponential-distribution

I am just starting out in R. I want to plot interval of times (the distribution is exponential) on x axis, with a tick mark in place every time the interval ends. If I have a string of times say (0.2, 0.8, 0.9 , 1.0) then the tick marks on the x axis would be on 0.2, 0.8, 0.9 and 1 respectively. With big data samples, I want my graph to look something like:

[image: Spike Train]

So after using,

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rexp(50, 0.2)
```

How can I go about it further, might I have to use rug function (which I am trying to learn how to use)? Can I also put time stamps on this graph?

### Edit

So I have modified my command and used:

```
x <- c(cumsum(rexp(50, 0.2)))
y <- rep(0, length(x))
plot(x,y)
rug(x)
```

and I have been able to get this:

[image: Revised Plot]

This result does the work, if it's just about that. However, is there a line of command I can use to edit this result as shown in the second picture, and get a result as shown in the first picture? I would like to just get these tick marks on a horizontal line instead of the whole plot. Or it's not possible?

Comment: put x into a data.frame, the you can use geom_rug in ggplot. How do the time stamps relate to the rug?

Comment: Can you please illustrate the code @RichardTelford, I just started in R and I get confused even with the simple commands. Time stamps don't relate to rug, I was just wondering out loud, it doesn't matter anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ggplot` you can use `geom_rug()` to .add a rug to the plot. First the data need to be made into a data.frame

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(1)
x <- rexp(50, 0.2)

ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x = x)) + geom_rug()
```

The rug is rather short (it seems to be a proportion of the graph height and not controllable).

The opposite would be to use `geom_vline` which will give lines the full length of the y-axis

```
#ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(xintercept = x)) + geom_vline() #doesn't work
ggplot(data.frame(x)) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x))
```

Answer (score 0):

`rug()` requires only a vector of values that describes where to draw the tickmarks (rugs). In case of plotting values `x` on the x-axis, those form the input data for the `rug` function. Type `?rug` to get further help.

```
# generate y values
y <- rexp(50, 0.2)
# split plotting area into two columns - optional
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(x, y)
rug(x)
# plot with both axes in log scale to show that rug adjusts to axes scale
plot(x, y, log = "xy")
rug(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @nya , thank you so much for your comment, this makes things much more clear. However, I have modified my question upon further clarification of things. Please let me know if you can help?